# How to call a method in controller on picklist change?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, force.com

```
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{! LimitSize}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{! paginationSizeOptions}" />    
</apex:selectList>
```

This is my pick list.

```
private String LimitSize = '';
public String getLimitSize() {
    return LimitSize;
}
public void setLimitSize(String LimitSize) {
    this.LimitSize = LimitSize;
}
public SelectOption[] paginationSizeOptions { 
        public get;
        private set;
}
public SiteController2(){
    String[] paginationSize  = new String[]{'2','5','10','200','250' };
    this.paginationSizeOptions = new SelectOption[]{};

    for (String c: paginationSize) {
        this.paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption(c,c));
    }

    LimitSize = paginationSize[0];
}
public checkLimitSize(){
   system.debug('Limit Size : '+LimitSize);
}
```

Now on change of picklist I want to assign LimitSize variable with selected value of picklist and call method checkLimitSize() to check the value. How can I do that?Thanks.

Comment: I believe this thread has your answer:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4910/calling-a-apex-controller-method-using-javascript-in-vf-page

Answer (score 2):

You can use **apex:actionFunction** component:

1. add actionFunction component to page

`<apex:actionFunction action="{!yourControllerMethod}" name="yourFunction"/>`

2. Add method to controller

`public PageReference yourControllerMethod(){
    //body of method
    checkLimitSize();
    return null;
}`

3. add actionFunction call on

`<apex:selectList onchange="yourFunction() ...."`

For more information read [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm).